# Strange linebreaks occur when exporting to csv from Datatable

Tags: sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv

I have a strange issue when I export my `DataTable` to CSV with `Powershell`: I get some line breaks and I am also not sure why I get the 
 #TYPE System.Data.DataRow

[image]

```
$query = "use [ISTABLocalDB]
SELECT  
    Item.[ID] as PartIdDB
    ,car.Kilometrage                
      FROM [ISTABLocalDB].[file].[Item] as Item
      INNER JOIN [ISTABLocalDB].[file].[ItemPart] as ItemPart ON Item.ID = ItemPart.  
  LEFT JOIN [ISTABLocalDB].[file].[ItemResourceFile] as ImageFile ON Car.ID = ImageFile.Item_ID
      where 
      Item.Type = 'P' -- means parts
      and ItemType.[Code] Not like '9001' -- car saved
      and ItemType.[Code]  in ('5000','5001','5002','5003','5003','5005','5006','9000');" 


    $extractFile = "$path $date.csv"


    $connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv  $extractFile -encoding "unicode" -Delimiter ";"

    $file= $extractFile
    (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $file
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `#Type` row by using the `-NoTypeInformation` switch on `Export-CSV` (or `-NTI` for short). The line breaks I would guess are occurring because your source data contains line breaks. I don't think Excel natively handles semi-colon `;` as a delimiter, but if you use its data import function you can manually define what the delimiter of the file is.

Comment: yeah i see there is a new line how exactly should i then handle that so it doesn't go down to a new row in the csv?

Comment: It should be OK because each item in the CSV will be wrapped in double quotes. However your screenshot shows that you've opened it in Excel but that Excel has not identified that ; is the delimiter. So either use Excel the data import options to define the delimiter when you open it in Excel, or change the delimiter to `,` (or just don't define `-Delimiter` on `Export-CSV` as comma is the default).

Comment: i tryed that too the same and nope it doesn't wraps its

Comment: You can use `| ? { $_ } |` to select only non-empty lines. `Get-Content $file | % {$_ -replace '"', ''} | ? { $_ } | Out-File $file`